# Displaying correct information in cellForRowAt

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I think I'm close, but seem to be confusing myself as I have access to all the data, but can't get it to behave.

I am trying to display a list of employees under their respective company (section) in a table in a table view.

My CoreData in respect to stored values and relationships is correct.  I know this by using print statements in various places.

Below is my code, but a summary of my issue relating to the `cellForRowAt` method is...

1. I can print a list of companies and their employees using `print("Company - \(company.name!)  Employee - \(employee.name!)")`

   - Company - Company1  Employee - Fred Smith
   - Company - Company1  Employee - Betty Boo
   - Company - Company2  Employee - GI Joe
   - Company - Company3  Employee - George Jungle
2. If I set `cell.textLabel?.text = allCompanies[indexPath.section].name`, I get the correct number of rows (based on employee.count per company) in each section, but it displays the the company name on each row per section
3. If I set `cell.textLabel?.text = employee.name!`, I only get the one employee returned across all rows.  The same employee in all sections.

*CoreData Entities*

Entity - Company
Attribute - name
Relationship - hasEmployee

Entity - Employee
Attribute - name
Relationship - hasCompany

```
var allCompanies: [Company] = []

func getCompanies() {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Company")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        allCompanies = try moc.fetch(request) as! [Company]
    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }
}

//MARK: - Fetched Results
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = { () -> NSFetchedResultsController<Employee> in

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Employee> = Employee.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()

func attemptFetch() {

    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! EmployeeCell

    for company in allCompanies {
        for employee in company.hasEmployee?.allObjects as! [Employee] {

//                print("Company - \(company.name!)  Employee - \(employee.name!)")
//                cell.textLabel?.text = employee.name!
                cell.textLabel?.text = allCompanies[indexPath.section].name
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `Company` instances as section and the employees as rows you might write

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! EmployeeCell

    let company = allCompanies[indexPath.section]
    let allEmployees = company.hasEmployee?.allObjects as! [Employee]
    let employee = allEmployees[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = employee.name
    return cell
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let company = allCompanies[section]
    return company.name
 }
```

But I recommend to use the capabilities of `NSFetchedResultsController` to handle the sections.

PS: The naming `hasEmployees` for an array is confusing because usually the prefix `has` or `is` indicates a `Bool`. Just name it `employees` and declare the array (actually a set) as non-optional.

Comment: vadian, as always, you are fantastic.  Thank you.